# Create Ref using React.createRef without using constructor in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

Basically, I have used `constructor` in `React` for only 3 reasons -

## 1. To initialize `state` like -

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { counter: 0 };
    }
}
```

but due to Babel's [class-field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) support, I don't use it anymore

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { counter: 0 };
}
```

## 2. To `bind` functions like -

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.increment.bind(this);
    }

    increment() {

    }
}
```

but due to `arrow` functions, I don't do it anymore

```
class App extends React.Component {
    increment = () => {

    }
}
```

## 3. To use `createRef` like -

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    }
}
```

So can I use `React.createRef` without using `constructor` in React?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can declare it as an class field just like `state`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { counter: 0 };
  inputRef = React.createRef();
}
```

Babel will transpile it into something like the code below in stage-2 presets.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { counter: 0 };
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const inputRef = React.createRef();

  return (
    <input ref={inputRef} />
  );
}
```

The only thing you *cannot* do, is pass the `ref` attribute to a functional component:

```
render() {
  // This won't work.
  return <MyFunctionalComponent ref={this.inputRef} />
}
```

---

More info from the official docs, [**here**](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components):

> You can, however, use the `ref` attribute inside a function component as long as you refer to a DOM element or a class component:

Answer (score 4):

you can create a ref with ref callbacks without using constructor. `<input ref={(element) => { this.inputRef = element; }} />` is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

On **class components** write like below:

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  inputRef = createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.inputRef}~~~
    );
  }
}
```

On **functional components** write like below:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div ref={inputRef}~~~
  );
};
```

Definitely, the referenced element is mutable object but it should persist for the full lifetime of the component. it is not my opinion, this words are for [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Exactly as you did with the state (with Babel's class-field support):

```
class App extends React.Component {
    inputRef = React.createRef();
}
```